# Reset modem Pirelli

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, modem

I tried to port-forward the port 80 in my modem so I could show my website to other people.

The thing is that when I try to go to the configuration panel of the modem, now the modem redirects me to my IP, instead of the modem. As the web front-end of it uses port 80.

The modem is this one: Pirelli Discus DRG A112

Does anyone know if I can reset it to the factory default configuration or stop port-forwarding port 80?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pinhole reset button on the back of the modem. Press and hold it for like 30 seconds - it will reset it to default factory settings.

But before doing that try connecting to the modem using `https://`. If the modem has the secure page enabled - you will be able to connect to it since it's using port 443 instead of 80.

Comment: Nevermind, someone suggested me to use :8080 instead of 80 and it worked. Thanks anyway